# Trying to use std::mutex and std::thread with OpenSSL

Tags: c++, multithreading, openssl, std

OpenSSL doesn't seam to have been migrated to the standard threading library, is this true? Am I stuck in 98? Has some kind soul created a wrapper?

```
lock_cs=OPENSSL_malloc(CRYPTO_num_locks() * sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
lock_count=OPENSSL_malloc(CRYPTO_num_locks() * sizeof(long));
```

Basically I'm hoping not to have to rewrite the code for every platform..

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Bob.

Comment: OpenSSL is written in C, not C++.  What "standard threading library" are you referring to?  Your example code is using POSIX threads.

Comment: Hi Sorry, I've a little practice using c++ std::thread/mutex etc, but the excerpt is from the Openssl/mttest.c file which I think I'm able to follow.   Big problem being that I need to test this thing on win64 / Linux and AIX... So if I can't wrap it into the std::  libraries, there's going to be a mountain of extra work..